# Gmail alias - Signup works, login doesn’t work

Tags: bug, login

If you have a Gmail account, *username@gmail.com*, Google allows you to use an alias like *username**+somealias**@gmail.com* and still redirect all emails to root email. (Notice the `+` sign.)

I just signed up on WorkPlace site with *usename+sitese@gmail.com* but for some reason the confirmation e-mail came from stackexchange instead and, not surprisingly, I cannot login using those credentials on Workplace. Upon login it tells me that *”The email or password is incorrect”*.

So, even if I initiated the signup on that site, it ended up to sign me up on this site instead.

Comment: It's called subaddressing. Stack exchange will not put your accounts together but keep them completely separate, no matter what Google does. Which email do you use when signing up?

Comment: I signed up with username@gmail.com and I want a completelly different account on a specific site using gmail’s feature, to simulate uniqueness

Comment: are you using a google login? You can have seperate logins/accounts on the same google account - I use + addressing for my alternate, and a normal google login for my main account.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek for my main account it is indeed a Google login, using google authorization

Comment: hm. That is *literally* the setup I use. Maybe try reviewing your login options on the main account to make sure you didn't accidentally set the +sitese account as a login option there, then reset the password on the alternate account?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek  the reset the password link says that “the email doesn’t exist in our records”, eventhough it’s sent to the same email where I received the “complete registration email”

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I think I found the problem. When I signup from **that** specific site, the confirmation comes from meta.stackexchange.com. So, even if I initiated the signup on **that** site, it ended up to sign me up on *this* site instead. Not sure where exactly is the problem coming from but the site in question is workplace site